# SVG embedded using <object> tag does not render in React app

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to show a svg based on a props value in a React component. I can show this using image tag, but using object tag does not work. 
So, this works-->

```
<svg {...props}> 
<image width="100%" xlinkHref={`/${props.svg}`}/> 
</svg>
```

But this does not-->

```
<object {...props} type="image/svg+xml" data={`/${props.svg}`} />
```

props have *height*, *width*, *x*, *y* and the *svg* image url to be rendered.
I want to render the svg as an svg and not as an image, how can I achieve it?

Comment: store svgs in a file and import it where you require

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r4v6rc , made a demo on this. Is that you need to achieve ?

Comment: @Raviteja these svgs are stored in different files and the value of "props.svg" is that filename.

Comment: @Jayavel Yes I wanted to do this, but for some reason same thing does not work for me. I think I should look at the wdth/height properties and other stuff. One more important part I missed to put in question is that this component is a child of another svg. That might have been causing issues.

Comment: @Sourabh86 could you please upload your codes in that demo, that might be helpful to find the root cause.

Comment: @Jayavel just wrap your object tag in an svg tag and it does not render anything, but it is usually possible to show an svg under another svg.